# Lightweight asp.net membership provider alternative

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, couchdb

Looking for a light weight alternative to the membership provider. Does such a thing exist?

It should allow for the creation and modification of accounts, nothing to fancy. A password reset would also be nice. Would be great if it didn't require a database but used some object database (couchdb, db40 etc). Basically as I wrote, a simple and light weight version of the membership provider.

Comment: I doubt you can expect a reasonable answer without providing at least basic requirements.

Comment: I don't really consider the SqlMembershipProvider to be heavyweight, although that doesn't change your database requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend [Artem XML Providers](http://aspnetxmlproviders.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=10136).

A full provider stack with XML backing store.

Perfect for small sites with few users as well as for demo apps.

Answer (score 0):

I just published a Membership and Roles providers that use CouchDB as the backed. You may download it from: http://couchdbnet.codeplex.com/